# .net application cannot consume asmx web service from windows 2008 server or windows 8

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-8, .net-3.5, asmx

I have an issue that is causing me a lot of frustration!

I have a .NET asmx web service hosted on a windows 2007 R2 server. This web service is using version 3.5 of the .NET framework.

I can instantiate and call a simple WebMethod from this web service without error from my windows forms based application (which also uses version 3.5 of the .NET framework) when installed on Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7.

However, when I attempt the same call from the same application when installed on a machine running either Windows 8 or Windows Server 2008 R2, I get instantionation errors (object not set...).

Comment: Suggestion: don't use ASMX services - they're nearly obsolete. Use WCF instead.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion John, but the web-service works fine in 99% of cases. If moving to WCF was a definite fix, I would do it, but I am not convinced this issue isn't permission based...

Answer (score 0):

Install the .NET Framework 3.5 on your Windows 8 to see if it helps. Find more info on [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the comment, I forgot to mention I do have version 2.0 and version 3.5 of the .NET Framework installed on the Windows 8 machines and it is installed on the Windows 2008 R2 server. I initially thought it was a 64bit issue, but my development machine is running Windows 7 64bit and everything works fine there...